# How does Runtime infer type at runtime?

Tags: c++, memory

Does compiler hard-code the rule in Machine Instructions how to read the memory at runtime?
ex:

```
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin >> n;
    cout << "n * 4 = " << n * 4 << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

My understanding on cin is it will stream bytes with space/line separated, if so when I give input as `5` the output is `n * 4 = 20` & it fine. But when I give input as `a` then reading the memory as int `0110 0001` it has to give me `97` right (I don't know how can we read 4 bytes (int) out of 1 byte (char)). If I make the type as `char` it works as expected.

char n => Input = 'a' & Output = 'n * 4 = 388'

int n => Input = 'a' & Output = 'n * 4 = 0' How ??

My main question how does runtime know how to read each memory unit?

Is it possible that runtime can read partial memory & know it is not complete?

Edit:

Thanks @john in comments. My doubt is clarified. All I wanted to know is runtime stores some information on what it supposed to read from memory & in some languages it throws error if it doesn't meet the criteria.

This is exactly what I was expecting
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/380347/how-do-variables-in-c-store-their-type

Comment: If you ever want to know the "machine instructions" *look at the assembly output of your compiled code*. All your answers are right there.

Comment: I'm not sure what this question is about. Are you asking "How can `cin` read different kinds of data?"

Comment: It seems you've just discovered [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII).

Comment: @idclev463035818 When just typed 'a' in console

Comment: Take a quick look at the ASCII table I linked to, and look up entry decimal 97.

Comment: @tadman Its not about ASCII, Initially I was thinking about dependent types in Agda where the type of list can encode the length in its type. I was wondering what if I give some randon input at runtime?

Comment: You're asking why you get 97 when you type `a` and I'm telling you **that is precisely why**. Whatever expectations you have from other languages will not necessarily apply in C++. This is a programming language that presumes you know what you're doing when you ask for something and will not second-guess you. `cin >> n` does exactly what you ask, it takes input from `cin` and puts it into the variable `n` as best it can.

Comment: Remember the principle *garbage in, garbage out*, which means for random input you will get random output. You're not doing any checks here, you're just multiplying whatever you get.

Comment: @PawanKumar I'm struggling to understand what you are asking, but you're clearly overthinking it. I/O in C++ is not very complicated. You've misunderstood something basic and now are tieing yourself in knots to justify that misunderstanding.

Comment: When you enter ’a’ for an `int`, the reading fails. Whether the variable is modified or not depends on the language version. Prior to C++11, your code has undefined behaviour; since C++11, `n` should be 0.

Comment: If you are reading an `int` and the input is `a` then all you have is an error because `a` is not a valid integer.

Comment: So that means the runtime knows exactly what to read from memory, how many bits & how to interpret it? which is encoded by compiler

Comment: What's being read from is the standard input (typically a console) I'm really unsure what you mean by reading from memory.

Comment: Plus what is being read is characters, not bits. And they are interpreted according to the type of the object being read. So yes the runtime does know what type of object it is reading to.

Comment: @john Thanks thats what I want to know.

Comment: you dont have to / should not edit your answer to add things like "question solved". The way to indicate that your question has been answered is to accept one of the answers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++ is statically typed.

```
int n; cin >> n;
```

will always read an integer (it supports several formats like binary, hex and decimal). When you input anything other than an integer (like `'a'`) it will fail and (since C++11) set `n` to 0.

```
char c; cin >> c;
```

ont the other hand will always read a char. Now `'a'` is a char, just as any digit is a char. Artithmetic operations on characters work with their respective Ascii-Codes (in the end a character is just an integral number). And `'a'` happens to have the Ascii-Code 97.